# Solution/library management in CLion

Tags: clion

Have CLion 1.2.2.

Made simple project:

```
main.cpp
a.hpp
a.cpp
b.hpp
b.cpp
```

What I want now is to move `a.hpp/a.cpp` into separate library (sub)project, same
for `b.hpp/b.cpp` and refer to them in main project CMakeList.txt

Is there a good way to do that?

More general question: how to handle several library (sub)projects which could be shared between quite a few final projects ("solutions" in Microsoft speak)

Found docs on project management in CLion seriously lacking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CLion, project management is currently done by editing the `CMakeLists.txt` file.  Everything CLion shows you comes from parsing that file.

Change your `CMakeLists.txt` from something like:

```
add_target(foo main.cpp a.cpp a.hpp b.cpp b.hpp)
```

to something like:

```
add_library(foolib a.cpp a.hpp b.cpp b.hpp)
add_target(foo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo foolib)
```

Comment: Thank you,but could I import library with it's own CmakeLists.txt, for example? Coud I have hierarchy of subprojects/libraries?

Comment: Generally this is done by putting all the source files for a library in its own directory with its own `CMakeLists.txt` and then using `add_directory` in the main `CMakeLists.txt` to add that subdirectory for cmake processing.

Comment: @legalize I think you mean [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html), unless the cmake command has changed since you posted your comment.